# SQL Server Join on Multiple Columns Joining Together

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a query where I am trying to join multiple columns together into one column while joining a table to convert the partnumber into an ID.

What is wrong with my query?

I get the error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

But I am not sure how to word it otherwise.

```
Select ID, Title
from dbo.features
unpivot
(
  Title
  for col in ([Features 1], [Features 2], [Features 3], [Features 4], [Features 5], [Features 6])
) un
order by partnumber, col;
(
JOIN    products.products
ON      Products.Products.PartNumber = dbo.features.PartNumber
)
```

Comment: remove the semicolon after `col;`?  pretty sure that's not your end of statement.  or do you mean to put the join after the from...

Comment: Didn't help :( thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps...

```
Select F.ID Feature_ID, F.Title Feature_Title
from dbo.features
INNER JOIN    products.products
  ON Products.Products.PartNumber = dbo.features.PartNumber
unpivot
(
  Title
  for col in ([Features 1], [Features 2], [Features 3], [Features 4], [Features 5], [Features 6])
) un
order by partnumber, col;
```

but to answer the question: **What is wrong with my query?**

**ANSWER:** 
Your join syntax is/was wrong.

Comment: Got an error The column name "Title" specified in the UNPIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the UNPIVOT argument.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The column 'PartNumber' was specified multiple times for 'un'.

Comment: @user3768157 then please update your question with the columns for each of your tables. How was xQbert supposed to know which column already exists?

Comment: Thanks xQbert but i still get errors.  The column name "Title" specified in the UNPIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the UNPIVOT argument.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The column 'PartNumber' was specified multiple times for 'un'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "F.ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "F.Title" could not be bound.

Comment: Yeah more info needed table structure/columns

Comment: @user3768157 Jeezus, they are mostly errors about which column belongs to which table. We are not mind readers, if you want an answer, then update your question with the relevant information! (in this case, the columns of your tables)